# Upper Bound with multiple classes - Java generics

Tags: java, generics, dictionary, upperbound

I need to accept a Map that can be either TypeA or TypeB like below.

```
 Map<Animal, List<TypeA/TypeB>>
```

How do I declare this? I cannot specify two classes for upper bounds.

```
 Map<Animal, List<? extends Object>> OR Map<Animal, List<Object>>
```

is too wide. I wanted to restrict it to TypeA or TypeB

Any better way?

Cannot wrap TypeA and TypeB with interface.

**EDIT:**
From the answers, I understand that, it is not possible with custom types.
The follow up questions is, if I just use `<? extends Object>`, how should I check the type of ? is either TypeA or TypeB. Should I use instanceof? Code sample?

Comment: If `TypeA` and `TypeB` are non-covariance types, then you don't have any options other than the `? extends Object`. If you don't want such a broad type, then you have to create some kind of relationship between the two types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious solution would be to introduce a supertype of `TypeA` and `TypeB` that contains the behaviour you require.

A different approach would be to use an adapter. To quote from ye olde Gang of Four book:

> Convert the interface of a class into another interface clients expect. Adapter lets class work together that couldn't otherwise because of incompatible interfaces.

So here we would introduce an adapter type (only with a better name than this).

```
interface Ab {
    void someOp();
}
```

Then we can wrap existing objects.

```
public static Ab asAb(final TypeA obj) {
    return new Ab() {
        public void someOp() {
            obj.someOp();
        }
    };
}
```

The map can use the adapter type as the value.

```
Map<Animal, List<Ab>>
```

When I have come across this issue in existing code, it has been because the map actually contains two disjoint maps. The easy solution there is to use two maps.

Comment: +1 for adapter since he explicitly said that he cannot extract a common interface

Comment: I cannot touch TypeA or TypeB. Would Adapter be still relevent?

Comment: @KevinRave Yup. Added a bit more explanation.

Comment: Though not a perfect solution in my case, there is nothing better than this.